# Could you, please, help me to understand this info from the Android SDK

Tags: android

I've been rereading this and can't make a sense of it, could you, probably explain it to me?

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register
>   broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a
>   Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when
>   first constructing the singleton.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

I fail to see why there's no need to subclass Application. I often subclass it so I can access application context from everywhere. So, what shall be the proper way according to this document?

Comment: Can you elaborate your usage of subclassing Application and using Application context?

Comment: @auselen I'm storing Application Context in a static field of my Application-derived class. I'm doing that in my Application's onCreate(). So I can then access that stored context from everywhere

Comment: I think they are just trying to warn you about possible leaks via usage of Application Context.

Comment: @auslen Could you give an example of such a leak (as Application Context is a singleton)

Comment: I was thinking something like the note in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29, meaning you don't leak that Context but you leak via that Context whenever that Context can get a reference to some other object.

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea is to **avoid overloading the Application class** but instead having multiple small singleton classes focused on different concerns.

That's probably what they mean by "more modular way".

Answer (score 1):

Normally people make the "Application" class so that they can store objects in it to persist the entire lifetime of the app or transfer between activities. I think what that line is saying that simply making it `static` would achieve the same purpose, in a more "modular" way.

As for application context, did you already know about `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: What's new about getApplicationContext()?